# asp.net mvc customize textbox for data search

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working wiht vs2010 with asp.mvc 4 and razor.
In my project into the database I have a table "person", I need to customize the textboxfor of asp.net mvc so while I type the name will show the results as in the figure attached.
Facebook is the search, I need to do is something like facebook people search

[image: textbox Search]

Comment: Look at something like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Try using the Bootstrap Typeahead jQuery plugin - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: This needs to be done on the client side and a web method returning json will be used. Use jquery autocomplete.

Comment: thanks, all your suggestions helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Some code that might be useful to get you started:

**VIEW:**

```
  // ...Other Stuff...

  <input type="text" name="PersonName" id="PersonName" />


  @section Scripts {

      @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

      $("#PersonName").autocomplete({

                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("SearchPerson", "Person")', type: "GET", 
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { Name: item.Name, Person: item.PersonID, value: item.Name };
                            }))
                        }
                    })

                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var selecteditem = ui.item;

                    // STUFF YOU WANT TO DO WITH THE SELECTED ITEM (like setting some HiddenField with an ID...)

                    // DEBUG:
                    //alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + selecteditem.Name : "Nothing selected");
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

  }
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    // GET : /Person/SearchPerson?term=term

    public ActionResult AutocompletePerson(string term)
    {

        var people = from p in db.Person
                     where p.Name.StartsWith(term)
                     select new { PersonID = p.PersonID, Name = p.Name)};

        return this.Json(people, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi I am trying to do the same and i followed your code and is working fine.Now i want to show image along with name.How to append image in autocomplete?

Comment: Hey. I have never done that, so I don't have any code on that matter. But these links might be useful: http://codeblogging.net/blogs/1/15/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911537/jquery-autocomplete-with-images
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670956/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-image Good luck!